# Из-за чего может быть такое отображение русского языка?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте,есть скрипт который отправляет команды игровому сервер через Rcon и получает ответ.
Но если в ответе содержится русский язык он его отображает совершено не правильно:

Ответ сервера:

```
А,Б,В,Г,Д,Е,Ё,Ж,З,И,Й,К,Л,М Н,О,П,Р,С,Т,У,Ф,Х,Ц,Ч,Ш,Щ,Ъ,Ы,Ь,Э,Ю,Я 000 а,б,в,г,д,е,ё,ж,з,и,й,к,л,м,н,о,п,р,с,т,у,ф,х,ц,ч,ш,щ,ъ,ы,ь,э,ю,я
```

Скрипт отображает:

```
   ►,◄,↕,‼,¶,§,☺,▬,↨,↑,↓,→,←,∟ ↔,▲,▼, ,!,",#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,,,-,., 000 0,1,2,3,4,5,Q,6,7,8,9,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
```

Ссылка на скрипт ниже.
Я не прошу разбираться в скрипте, просто по смыслу ,из-за чего такое может быть?
[Скрипт](https://yadi.sk/d/TO7zclcaZP7Mi)

Сделал скрипт который расшифровывает эти данные, при условии что все данные на русском языке.
Вдруг кому пригодится:

```
$key = Array('0' => 16, '1' => 17, '2' => 18, '3' => 19, '4' => 20, '5' => 21, '6' => 1, '7' => 22, '8' => 23, '9' => 24, '10' => 25, '11' => 26, '12' => 27, '13' => 28, '14' => 29, '15' => 30, '16' => 31, '17' => 32, '18' => 33, '19' => 34, '20' => 35, '21' => 36, '22' => 37, '23' => 38, '24' => 39, '25' => 40, '26' => 41, '27' => 42, '28' => 43, '29' => 44, '30' => 45, '31' => 46, '32' => 47, '33' => 48, '34' => 49, '35' => 50, '36' => 51, '37' => 52, '38' => 53, '39' => 81, '40' => 54, '41' => 55, '42' => 56, '43' => 57, '44' => 58, '45' => 59, '46' => 60, '47' => 61, '48' => 62, '49' => 63, '50' => 64, '51' => 65, '52' => 66, '53' => 67, '54' => 68, '55' => 69, '56' => 70, '57' => 71, '58' => 72, '59' => 73, '60' => 74, '61' => 75, '62' => 76, '63' => 77, '64' => 78, '65' => 79 );
$sym = Array('0' => 192, '1' => 193, '2' => 194, '3' => 195, '4' => 196, '5' => 197, '6' => 168, '7' => 198, '8' => 199, '9' => 200, '10' => 201, '11' => 202, '12' => 203, '13' => 204, '14' => 205, '15' => 206, '16' => 207, '17' => 208, '18' => 209, '19' => 210, '20' => 211, '21' => 212, '22' => 213, '23' => 214, '24' => 215, '25' => 216, '26' => 217, '27' => 218, '28' => 219, '29' => 220, '30' => 221, '31' => 222, '32' => 223, '33' => 224, '34' => 225, '35' => 226, '36' => 227, '37' => 228, '38' => 229, '39' => 184, '40' => 230, '41' => 231, '42' => 232, '43' => 233, '44' => 234, '45' => 235, '46' => 236, '47' => 237, '48' => 238, '49' => 239, '50' => 240, '51' => 241, '52' => 242, '53' => 243, '54' => 244, '55' => 245, '56' => 246, '57' => 247, '58' => 248, '59' => 249, '60' => 250, '61' => 251, '62' => 252, '63' => 253, '64' => 254, '65' => 255 );
$str = ;//Получение этой строки
for ($i = 0; $i < iconv_strlen($str); $i++) {
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($key); $a++) {
    if(ord($str[$i]) == $key[$a]) {
    $test[] = $sym[$a];
    }
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
    $prefix = $prefix.chr($test[$i]);
}
echo "<br>";
echo "Было:";
echo "<br>";
echo $str;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Стало:";
echo "<br>";
echo $prefix;
```

Comment: а в какой кодировке сервер отсылает ответ? Не в CP866? Скрипт вроде как в Windows-1251 интерпретирует

Comment: Если чесно, не знаю.
Можно ли это как то проверить?